# How to solve $\frac{1}{\kappa}\tanh^{-1}(\kappa t)+bt=c$ for $t$

Tags: exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

I want to solve this equation for $t$:
$$
\frac{1}{\kappa}\tanh^{-1}(\kappa t)+bt=c,
$$
given that $\kappa$ is a constant, and $b$ and $c$ are functions not in terms of $t$.

I tried to convert it into the form of natural logarithms and transform it with the power of $e$ like below:
$$
e^{bt}+\kappa te^{bt}+\kappa te^c=e^c
$$

However, $t$ lies on both power of $e$ and the linear position, and I have been stuck at extracting $t$ for hours.

How can I get the solution to the equation? Is there any clever way to extract the solution?

Comment: It is likely that this cannot be done analytically, some sort of numerical approximation may be required.

Comment: @WW1 So I need to use the series expansion of $tanh^{-1}$ to make the approximation instead of doing it analytically?

Comment: maybe Newton's Method ...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: @WW1 Newton's Method is a good method to approximate the solution for a determined or short equation. However, it will become so complicated after the second iteration that Mathematica cannot compute the expressions of solutions. It seems that series expansion is a better approximation in this scenario even though I have to carefully define the valid domain of solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\kappa}\tanh^{-1}(\kappa t)+bt=c\tag 1$$ is an highly transcendental equation and then you will require some numerical method for obtainin the solution.

In fact, there is an analytical solution. Rewrite $(1)$ as
$$\kappa t=\tanh (\kappa  (c-b t)) \tag 2$$
Let $x=\kappa  (c-b t)$ to make
$$\frac{c \kappa -x}{b}=\tanh(x)= \frac {e^{2x}-1 } {e^{2x}+1 } \tag 3$$ which leads to
$$e^{-2x}=-\frac{x+(b-c \kappa)}{x-(b+c \kappa)} \tag 4$$ which has solutions in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$ in the linked paper).

This being said, it is not very useful from a practical point of view.

Just think about numerical methods.

**Edit**

Equation $(2)$ can rewrite and look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=x+b\tanh(x)-c \kappa\qquad \text{where} \qquad x=\kappa  (c-b t)$$

Assuming $b>0$ and $c \kappa >0$, we face an increasing function since
$$f'(x)=1+b \,\text{sech}^2(x)\quad > 0 \quad \forall x$$ Starting Newton method with $x_0=0$ will give as an estimate
$$x_1=\frac{c \kappa }{b+1}$$

Trying with $b=\pi$ and $c \kappa=12.345$, Newton iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 2.9807374 \\
 2 & 9.0248926 \\
 3 & 9.2034074
\end{array}
\right)$$

Doing the same with $b=\frac 1\pi$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 9.3642626 \\
 2 & 12.026690
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you!! However, as I have said in the question, $b$ and $c$ are functions not in terms of $t$ so Newton Method might not a good solution for this. Lambert W function seems like a good but very complex solution. Anyway, I think Lambert function can solve my problem.